# Negative Positioning Absolute Div Issue With Mobile Browser

Tags: html, css

I've run into an issue.  I have a div absolute positioned and am hiding it off screen using a negative right value.  This is fine on desktop browsers, but I'm finding on mobile safari that I can horizontally scroll and basically swipe the element into view.

I made a very simple version of what I'm attempting below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<!-- v3 -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Block Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.disrupt {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: -150px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body >
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="disrupt">
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

In a desktop browser it works fine, in Safari and Chrome on an iPhone I'm able to scroll the hidden portion of the disrupt block into view.  Chrome on android seems to work fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not set the width to 150px and right:0px;? Wouldn't this be the same but without a hidden part of any div?

Comment: I can't scroll it into view on my iPad Air 2 (Safari)

Comment: Can't horizontally scroll it into view on my iPhone 5s Safari either :)

Comment: Hide it by positioning it far off to the left?

Comment: Is there any update about the solution?